# Right configure hproxy.cfg on OpenShift service

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift

Now, I have deployed my web-application **TomographySoftwareWebSite.war** on Tomcat 7 gear on OpenShift. Basicly when I tried to 
my url application

> http://tomography-antonov.rhcloud.com/

I've got 503 No server is available to handle this request. Then I changed a little bit my hproxy.cfg file. And change this

```
listen stats 127.11.87.3:8080
mode http
stats enable
stats uri /
```

listen express 127.11.87.2:8080

```
cookie GEAR insert indirect nocache
option httpchk GET /

balance leastconn
server local-gear 127.11.87.1:8080 check fall 2 rise 3 inter 2000 cookie local-5328ac845973cacd8500016d
```

on

listen stats 127.11.87.3:8080
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /

listen express 127.11.87.2:8080

```
cookie GEAR insert indirect nocache
option httpchk GET /TomographySoftwareWebSite

balance leastconn
server local-gear 127.11.87.1:8080 check fall 2 rise 3 inter 2000 cookie local-5328ac845973cacd8500016d
```

then my application starts work on

> http://tomography-antonov.rhcloud.com/TomographySoftwareWebSite/

How should I change configuration in order to start working with?

> http://tomography-antonov.rhcloud.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deploy your application to the root context (rename your war file ROOT.war),